# Pipenv shell cannot call the right alembic

Tags: python

I have a question on how pipenv works. My scenario is as below: 
I installed a python package called `alembic` in python 2.7 (`alembic2.7`). Then I create a python 3.7 env. In this env, I install `alembic` again with Pipfile. This `alembic` is in python 3.7 (`alembic3.7`).

Now comes to my problem:
I first start `pipenv shell` with this python 3.7 env. Then I run `alembic xxx` in the shell. The problem is this command refers to `alembic2.7`, rather than `alembic3.7`. If i run `pipenv run alembic xxx`, it will use `alembic3.7`.

In case you are not familiar with python `alembic` package, it is a python package that installs a linux command to the bash env. 
I am confused on this difference. My understanding of pipenv is that all the commands running in the pipenv shell equals `pipenv run command`. Could I get clarified on this?